# How do I sort rows using SQLite in Android with a rawquery method?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm using the following method to get data from a table:

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_SWIMMERLAPS + " * "
  + KEY_SPONSOR + " AS result FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
```

I was wondering if this can be edited to **sort the results by KEY_SWIMMERLAPS**. I thought the following would work:

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_SWIMMERLAPS + " * "
  + KEY_SPONSOR + " AS result FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_SWIMMERLAPS + " DESC");
```

However, I get an error because KEY_SWIMMERLAPS is not a string:

*The method rawQuery(String, String[]) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)*

Comment: Post the full error/exception-message here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You used the second argument on the `rawQuery` method and expected to be used as an order clause. That is not the case. The second argument is used to provide values for `?` placeholders in your SQL query string. Using the following should do the trick:

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_SWIMMERLAPS + " * "
            + KEY_SPONSOR + " AS result FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ORDER BY "+ KEY_SWIMMERLAPS+" DESC", null);
```